# find list contains from int array list

Tags: c#, asp.net

hi i am trying to find list.contains from my int array basically i am matching list items from my int array

```
int[] questionName =
{
    19294,
    19300,
    20575,
    20826,
    20827
};

var ans = (from answer in db.tblAnswers
    where answer.tblQuestion.bIsRequired == true
        && questionName.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(answer.nQuestionID))
        &&  (answer.strAnswer!=" " || answer.strAnswer.Trim()==string.Empty)
        && answer.nQuestionnnaireId==Convert.ToInt32(Session["FormId"].ToString())
    select answer).ToList();

List<int> list = new List<int>();
foreach (var i in ans) list.Add(i.nID);
if (list.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(questionName)))
{
    PopulateSurvey();
}
```

but when i run the page i got run time error that

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32[]'
>   to type 'System.IConvertible'.

I want to match id's from my linq query in my int array. If there is a way please let me know.

Comment: You cannot convert a `int[]` to an `int`. Perhaps you want to convert every single item . But why they are already Integers?

Comment: What is the type of `nQuestionId` in the database?

Comment: `questionName` is an array, you can't convert an array to an integer. It's not clear what you're trying to check with `list.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(questionName))`

Comment: no typecast array to int
if nQuestion(list.Contains(questionName))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the line

```
  list.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(questionName))
```

since questionName is `int[]` (**array**) you can't convert it into a single `int`. You may want either to find out

If `list` contains **all** `questionName` values (and may be some more items)

```
list.Intersect(questionName).OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(questionName.OrderBy(x => x))
```

Or if `list` contains **at least one** `questionName` value

```
list.Intersect(questionName).Any()
```

Comment: `SequenceEqual` requires the items in both lists to be in the same order, which may not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but it looks like what you need is to invoke `PopulateSurvey` if *any* of the ids retrieved from the database is included in `questionName`. In that case you can do the following:

```
if(list.Intersect(questionName).Any())
    PopulateSurvey();
```

Additional suggestion: do not retrieve the whole records from the database if all you need is the id. So: `var list = ... select answer.nId` (instead of `select answer`), note also that by doing this you don't need to manually generate the list anymore.

**UPDATE**: If what you need is all the items in `list` to be contained in `questionName`, use the following (`OrderBy` is needed because `SequenceEqual` requires the items to be in the same order in both lists):

```
list.Intersect(questionName).OrderBy(x=>x).SequenceEqual(questionName.OrderBy(x=>x))
```

Comment: hi i wants to match my all array items of int[] questionName =
        {
            19294,
            19300,
            20575,
            20826,
            20827
        }; this one if all match than go into if condition otherwise skip the if part

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through the 'questionName' array.

Then for every item in it, check if the list contains it.

Or with Linq you can convert questionName to a list with ToList. After that you can do some magic.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line

```
if (list.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(questionName))) //you are trying to convert an array to int
```

If you want to check that if questionName is a subset of list then change if condition to the following

```
if (!questionName.Except(list).Any())
```